# My SpringMVC application does not interpret taglibs

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

My JSP`s does not interpret Spring taglibs.
Please have a look at the code and the result errors:

The View is as follows:

```
<!-- TagLibs -->
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="${s:mvcUrl('AHC#HandleArticle').arg(0, Programacao de Computadores).build()}">Programacao de Computadores</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Controller:

```
package com.filipecanattodev.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.filipecanattodev.model.Discipline;


@Controller
public class ArticlesHandlerController {

    @RequestMapping("/HandleArticle")
    public ModelAndView HandleArticle(Discipline discipline){
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("ListOfArticles");
        return view;

    }

}
```

Configurations is as follows:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { HomeController.class })
public class AppWebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver InternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return 

}
```

The error is as follows:

> The browser show: HTTP Status 404 -The requested resource is not available.

And my url change from `http://localhost:8080/filipecanattodev/` to `http://localhost:8080/filipecanattodev/$%7Bs:mvcUrl('AHC#HandleArticle').arg(0, Programacao de Computadores).build()}`

Comment: Do you have jstl libraries on your classpath? From what I remember (it's been a while since I've worked with JSTL), the servlet container will evaluate them if jstl libraries are on the classpath (jstl-core, etc).

Comment: I`ve already done this verification, the libraries are in my classpath because it was declared at pom.xml

Comment: The point is that the spring framework does not convert the instruction made by the taglib to html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved changeing the version of web.xml from 2.3 to 3.0.